# Multiple LIKE, OR MySql Queries Match

Tags: mysql, sql

Search for: 'chemist'

Problem: query which will match a string like 'onechemist' but not 'chemist'.

```
SELECT id,name FROM `records` 
WHERE name LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($q) ."%'
```

This alternate try won't work:

```
SELECT id,name FROM `records` 
WHERE name LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($q) ."%'  
OR name LIKE '". mysql_real_escape_string($q) ."%' 
OR name LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($q) ."'
```

How could I compile the above into one single query that will match any field which has the string or optimize the query into a better expression?

Comment: Your first query *should* match `'chemist'` as well. According to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html), `%` is a wildcard that "matches any number of characters, even zero characters"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$q` is holding 'chemist', it will match a `name` that is also 'chemist`. In that case, your first query should work. Try double checking your values.

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `records` 
WHERE `name` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($q)."%'";
```

PS - Your 2nd query will pull the same results as your 1st.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for this. for example,

```
SELECT id,name FROM `records` where name REGEXP '^onechemist'
```

It will match names starts with **onechemist**